# JWPlayer Error Loading player

Tags: jquery, jwplayer

I use  JW Player in my Wordpress.
And get this error
Error Loading player.
No playable source found.

i get this only on my mobile. In Firefox and Safari it works, nut customer told that in his PC in Firefox and Safari it doesn't work.

```
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
                    sources: [{
                      file: "http://www.mydomain.com/v/v.flv",
                      width: "480",
                      height: "270"
                    }]
                });
```

Comment: `.flv` assumes Flash, and your mobile device might not support that.

Comment: And how about customer browsers???

Comment: They don't have a Flash player installed either?

Comment: In that case, can you place a demo online for others here to try and see what's happening?

Comment: Demo is working, the file format is mp4. My is flv. Any ideas?

Comment: Not unless you put your own file online somewhere so I can see.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem when Flash isn't installed, so I'd make doubly sure they have Flash installed properly. Otherwise, the movie file works just fine (tested on Mac (Chrome, Safari, FF) and Windows 8 (MSIE 10 'desktop version', FF)).

Comment: Do the flv videos works on Mobiles(Samsung, iPhone)?

Comment: Please provide a link so we can debug the problem, thanks